# What went wrong with my card flip animation in android?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

As mentioned in the title, I was trying to implement a card flip animation with reference to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnXWcGmLHHs.

Though the code in the video is in Kotlin, I managed to find a Java equivalent code in the comment section. However, when I ran the program and clicked the button, I was faced with this issue,

```
W/PropertyValuesHolder: Method set() with type float not found on target class class com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
W/PropertyValuesHolder: Method get() with type null not found on target class class com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
```

I have looked through my code several times but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code. Here is my code.

Activity's code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CardFlip extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView frontCard, backCard;
    private Button buttonFlip;

    private AnimatorSet frontAnim, backAnim;
    private boolean isFront = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.card_flip);
        float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        frontCard = findViewById(R.id.card_front);
        backCard = findViewById(R.id.card_back);
        buttonFlip = findViewById(R.id.button_flip);
        buttonFlip.setOnClickListener(onFlip);

        frontCard.setCameraDistance(8000 * scale);
        backCard.setCameraDistance(8000 * scale);

        frontAnim = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.front_animator);
        backAnim = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.back_animator);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onFlip = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFront) {
                frontAnim.setTarget(frontCard);
                backAnim.setTarget(backCard);
                frontAnim.start();
                backAnim.start();
                isFront = false;
            } else {
                frontAnim.setTarget(backCard);
                backAnim.setTarget(frontCard);
                backAnim.start();
                frontAnim.start();
                isFront = true;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Activity's XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CardFlip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_front"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Front Card"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_back"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Back Card"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:alpha="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_flip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flip"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_front" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Front Animation Code (in animator directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator>
        android:valueFrom = "0"
        android:valueTo = "180"
        android:propertyName = "rotationY"
        android:duration = "1000"
    </objectAnimator>
    <objectAnimator>
        android:valueFrom = "1.0"
        android:valueTo = "0.0"
        android:propertyName = "alpha"
        android:startOffset = "500"
        android:duration = "1"
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
```

Back Animation Code (in animator directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator>
        android:valueFrom = "1.0"
        android:valueTo = "0.0"
        android:propertyName = "alpha"
        android:duration = "0"
    </objectAnimator> 
    <objectAnimator>
        android:valueFrom = "-180"
        android:valueTo = "0"
        android:propertyName = "rotationY"
        android:repeatMode = "reverse"
        android:duration = "1000"
    </objectAnimator>
    <objectAnimator>
        android:valueFrom = "0.0"
        android:valueTo = "1.0"
        android:propertyName = "alpha"
        android:startOffset = "500"
        android:duration = "0"
    </objectAnimator>  
</set>
```

Any help to point out what I did wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After slowly looking through my code again, I realised that I mistyped my animations code.

Instead of this (using front animation code as an example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator>
        android:valueFrom = "0"
        android:valueTo = "180"
        android:propertyName = "rotationY"
        android:duration = "1000"
    </objectAnimator>
    <objectAnimator>
        android:valueFrom = "1.0"
        android:valueTo = "0.0"
        android:propertyName = "alpha"
        android:startOffset = "500"
        android:duration = "1"
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
```

It should have been this instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:duration="1000"
    />
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="1"
    />
</set>
```

I corrected the back animation code as well and everything works now